# nagios nrpe plugin output not complete

Tags: monitoring, freebsd, nagios, pfsense, nrpe

I have written a small script to check the states of PfSense, and using this script to get the output in nagios, through NRPE...

Here is the script

> used=`pfctl -s state | wc -l | bc | cut -c1-5 | bc`
>
> echo "States consumed=$used"

Normal output of the script is as follows (as it runs on the client.

```
States consumed=25519
```

But the issue is that when the same script is ran through NRPE from the nagios server, I get this command.

```
States consumed=0
```

But when I put anything in the variable "used" , for example pass it value of 123, or abc,,it is visible on the nagios server through nrpe...
What can be the issue here? I have tried every possible solution from my side, since last 5 days..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is "pfctl" in the PATH for nagios user?  I would use the absolute path in the script.

Comment: yes, thats why i am getting an output, otherwise script wont run at all

Comment: I don't mean the check script called by nrpe.  I mean the pfctl command itself (I'm not familiar with FreeBSD, so I don't know if that's standard, or if it's in /usr/sbin and /usr/sbin isn't in the default PATH for nagios user).  From what you've pasted, you're calling "pfctl" and assuming that the nagios user can find it in its PATH.

Comment: got it. i am running it with /sbin/pfctl ...now i have added the nrpe user to WHEELS group, but still nrpe is unable to run the command pfctl..

Comment: You may have to invoke your script using sudo.  You can restrict nagios user to only that command run by adding something like this to the sudoers file: "nagios ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script" and then changing your nrpe.cfg so that you're running "sudo /path/to/script".  See if that works.  It's possible pfctl won't run as non-root, even with a user in the right group.  Again, I'm not a BSD user so I'm not sure if that's the case.

Comment: i was trying not to use sudo, but as it was last resort, that i had left with..so its working now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is it because of the user that the script runs as?

Comment: the permission of script is 777, which means anyone can execute this command. but with which user nrpe runs the scripts?

Comment: What user is the nrpe daemon running as?  That's the user that will run the script.